# PHP 7.4.2 [extension] build errors on Windows

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-2019, saprfc

I am using a package (SAP RFC Connector) for some time now that is retrieved from here https://github.com/gkralik/php7-sapnwrfc

The package is working as expected on all PHP versions until 7.4.2 with source build.

I've built the **php_sapnwrfc.dll** from source with both **VS2015** and **VS2019** but I am unable to get it working due to these errors, that I am unable to solve.

For building, I've used this procedure:

1. https://gkralik.github.io/php7-sapnwrfc/building.html#building-on-windows
2. https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2

Is there someone out there that knows how to solve this?

With **VS2019** I got this error but no one knows what it means, especially the warning with the **core number.**

> Warning: PHP Startup:
>
> Can't load module 'C:/ownprograms/wamp/bin/php/php7.4.2/ext/php_sapnwrfc.dll' as it's linked with 14.24, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0

With **VS2015** I got this error but this is due to compiler.

> [17-Feb-2020 10:48:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sapnwrfc: Unable to initialize module
>
> Module compiled with build ID=API20190902,TS,VS16
>
> PHP    compiled with build ID=API20190902,TS,VC15
>
> These options need to match

PHP version: **7.4.2 TS**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone got my problem solved, here is his reply.

> Try with the attached DLLs. I've built it for both 7.4.2 and 7.4.3
>   with extension version 1.3.0, vc15, ts and x64. It should work.
>   php_sapnwrfc.zip
>
> For any PHP version > 7.2 except master branch you need to use
>   VC15(Visual Studio 2017). I saw in your trace that you were using VC16
>   (Visual Studio 2019).

I can confirm that I tried building it with VS2015 and VS2019, not with VS2017.

Thank you, the issue is solved.